# HTML css dynamic div/elements positioning

Tags: html, css

I made this design, that contains 2 types of content boxes, one which contains pictures and one that doesn't. All the boxes that don't have a picture have the same size. And the bottom margin should also be equal like this:

[image]

But because the boxes with pictures are bigger, and I'm using "float" the bottom boxes are being placed according to the bottom margin of the biggest box at the top, which causes it to leave a lot of blank space in between.

[image]

Is there any way to float the bottom boxes under the small boxes? I have tried both with floats and "displays" but nothing seems to work.
 This is my code:

```
    <div class="contentBox">
      <div class="contentBoxHead">
      </div>

      <div class="contentBoxPicture">
        <img src=" /categoria/articulo/images/" />
      </div>

      <div class="contentBoxDescription">
        <h2 class="contentBoxDescriptionText">
        </h2>
        <h3 class="contentBoxDescriptionText">
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

...

```
.contentBox{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

I have removed all the CSS related to the inner child divs of "contentBox" for it doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Please note that this is for a CMS type of site and I am trying to make this work the same way if all the boxes have pictures or not, and even if the order is completely different. For that reason I can't hardcode the positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is achievable with CSS only solution. But this is basically so called *masonry* layout. You can achieve it with e.g. this JavaScript library: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked great! although I was trying hard to avoid using a lot of js, looks like there's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

put the divs with content in one div and image one in another div.

for ex.

```
<div class="content_description">
 <div class="content_1"></div>
 <div class="content_2"></div>
</div>
<div class="content_image">
  <img src=""></img>
</div>
```

and then put css like

```
.content_description {
    width : 300px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
.content_image {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

cover all of this with another div where you define your float left.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need very fine control over the content flow then you can use CSS columns. I prepared a little demo for you where you can see there is no float, content is wrapping, height is properly preserved.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/pesoto/edit?html,css,output

Have fun and explore CSS3 features, theres a lot of good stuff there. :)